# downloadable item product selling cart with filter

Tags: magento, opencart, prestashop, cart

I want to sell downloadable product like: video files, pdf files, word documents, text documents etc.

And also my storefront should have filtering feature.

I have option for following cart in my hosting control panel:
Abantecart, Opencart 1.5, PrestaShop etc. Actually I am accessing mochahost cPanel.

To make a storefront of downloadable products with filtering feature, Which free cart product should I choose?

Comment: Big, proven, free, plus easy customization:  WooCommerce   It's a classic for a reason.    The real issue is: how is the rest of your website managed?  Language? Server?  # of hits projected / day? You definitely want tools that easily integrate, and have an active feedback and improvement system.  (Open source on Github?)

Comment: PHP, HTML, JSP, Tomcat 5.5 are supported. I have "Business" hosting plan from mochahost "http://www.mochahost.com/webhosting.php".

Comment: PHP or Java Management system?  (Symphony, Laravel, Wordpress?  dotCMS, Magnolia, Hippo, Jahia, OpenCMS?)  I'd pick one of those first, then choose a storefront that integrates nicely.  If you are just starting out, and don't expect more than 5K to 10K hits a day, Wordpress / WooCommerce is way easy.  If bigger growth than that, I'd think I'd be looking at Java implementation.

Comment: I checked demo for some of them. All of them seems to have that features. But uploading API is chargeable. Do any of them have free upload API ?

Comment: All I can say is I just spent close to 200 hours setting up my Prestashop site before discovering (with a sickening sensation in my stomach) that the back end order management is horribly structured and not manageable at all.  So I would STRONGLY suggest you try them all and don't worry about how the site looks, just make a test product, a test order, and envision actually handling that order.  Then decide based on that and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Big, proven, free, plus easy customization: WooCommerce.  It's a classic for a reason.

The real issue is: how is the rest of your website managed? What software languages are you intending? Server? # of hits projected / day? You definitely want tools that easily integrate, and have an active feedback and improvement system. (Open source on Github?)

PHP or Java Content Management system? (Symphony, Laravel, Wordpress? dotCMS, Magnolia, Hippo, Jahia, OpenCMS?) I'd pick one of those first, then choose a storefront that integrates nicely. If you are just starting out, and don't expect more than 5K to 10K hits a day, Wordpress / WooCommerce is way easy. If bigger growth than that, I'd think I'd be looking at Java implementation.

Reference your comment on Uploading API costing money.

- So download a free version, and write an upload tool yourself. Shouldn't be a big deal.
- And hey, how much are these guys charging, anyway?  What is your time worth?
- I thought you were selling downloaded items.. why would your customers be uploading anything anyway?  In fact, why is an upload tied to the shopping cart in the first place?  (I can see letting folks upload quality content, then earning credit, but that doesn't have to be directly tied to the shopping cart...)
- You will certainly be able to find sample code to safely allow users to upload content.